# Are random effects justified if there is no variability between groups?

Tags: random-effects-model, lm

I'm looking for more of a substantive ( but also a statistical ) answer.
If in the empty model (just intercept) there is no variability at level-2, should HLM still be applied just because the data is theoretically nested (employees in teams) ?
Will a linear model suffice in this case?

If you have an answer for me I would appreciate a bibliographical reference as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always *some* variability at level 2, even if it is very small.  But there could be *more* variability at level 2 after including some level 1 variables.

More basically, though, if employees are nested in teams then the point of multi-level models is that the data are not independent. People within teams will be more alike (or, possibly, more different, depending on how teams are selected) than people across teams. To show independence you'd have to show that this is not the case. I don't see how this could be done.

Comment: But if the team level variance component turns out to be zero (or it is essentially indistinguishable from zero), then this would imply independence.

Comment: @Wolgang- That's exactly what I thought.

Comment: @Wolfgang Not necessarily. Independence requires 0 covariance but you can have dependent data that has 0 variance, e.g. if the shape of the relationship is a U .

Comment: @PeterFlom True. But under normality (which is the standard assumption about the random effects in multilevel models), independence and zero covariance are synonymous. The point is: If the variance component ends up being estimated to be zero (or essentially zero), then this is the same as just leaving that variance component out of the model. I would not suggest to do this a priori, but if that's what the data are showing, then you will get the exact same results whether you use the multilevel model or just a standard linear model.